# NGINX server blocks doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, docker, nginx

I know it's not appropriate place to ask question about nginx but I stack with some issue for a few days and still have no idea how to solve a problem.

I would like to use nginx to redirect user from domain.com:3001 to sub.domain.com. Application on port 3001 is running in docker container, I didn't add any files in directory sites-available/sites-enabled. I have added two server blocks (vhosts) in my conf.d directory. In server block I set $upstream and resolver according to record in my /etc/resolv.conf file. The problem is that when I test in browser sub.domain.com every time I receive information that IP address could not be connected with any server (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN) or 50x errors.

However, when I run curl sub.domain.com from the server I receive 200 with index.html response, this doesn't work when I run the same command from my local PC. Server domain is in private network. Have you any idea what my configuration files lack of?? Maybe there is some issue with the listen port when app is running in docker or maybe there is something wrong with the version of nginx? When I installed nginx there was empty conf.d directory, with no default.conf. I am lost...

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is my configuration files:

server.conf:

```
server 
{
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  sub.domain.net;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cer.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

    #set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    #real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    #real_ip_recursive on;
#    location / {
#        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }

    location / {
        resolver 10.257.10.4;
        set $upstream https://127.0.0.1:3000;

        proxy_pass $upstream;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`enter code here`
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

    #error_page  404              /404.html;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

nginx.conf

#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

Comment: If you're aware it's not an appropriate place to ask about `nginx`, why did you ask anyway?

Comment: I dig down internet looking for solutions and found some similar posts on stack overflow concerning nginx. I am hopefull someone here will be able to help me as well.

Comment: The `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error in your browser has nothing to do with your Nginx server.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I am wondering why subdomain still doesn't work... I cannot use this subdomain from anywhere but from server. Any idea?